# OpenCV Python kernel crashes when clicking the trackbar

Tags: python, opencv, trackbar

I am trying to create a simple trackbar to test some edge detection, and I've been following the official opencv tutorial from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d5c/tutorial_canny_detector.html) in Python. When I run the code, the window is created and I can see the sliders, but when I click the sliders, the kernel crashes.

I tried this with some other code example from the internet and it crashed then as well. Basically the moment I click in the region of the slider, the kernel crashes. I know that one thing you seem to need to do in macs is increase the `waitKey` time and I did do that.

How can I make this work?

```
def canny_threshold(low_val, src, src_gray):
    low_threshold = low_val
    img_blur = cv.blur(src_gray, (3,3))
    detected_edges = cv.Canny(img_blur, low_threshold, low_threshold * RATIO)
    mask = detected_edges != 0
    dst = src * (mask[:,:, None].astype(src.dtype))
    return dst


src = cv.imread("magpie_house.jpeg")
src_gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def nothing(x):
    pass


cv.namedWindow(WINDOW_NAME)
cv.startWindowThread()
cv.createTrackbar(TITLE_TRACK_BAR, WINDOW_NAME, 0, MAX_LOW_THRESHOLD, nothing)
cv.setTrackbarPos(TITLE_TRACK_BAR, WINDOW_NAME, 50)


while True:
    COUNTER += 1
    if COUNTER >= 700:
        break
    low_val = cv.getTrackbarPos(TITLE_TRACK_BAR, WINDOW_NAME)
    dst = canny_threshold(low_val, src, src_gray)
    cv.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, dst)
    if cv.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
    

cv.waitKey(1)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please post relevant code

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/kernel-crashing-on-clicking-trackbar/9839

Answer (score -1):

It appears that there is a known [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues?page=3&q=trackbar) on macs regarding trackbars.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, copy over the relevant information with attribution to pair with the link :)